# How to optimize for loops which create a new data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have created a code which works, but I believe it could run faster by replacind the `for` loops.

**OLD VERSION (feel free to skip)**

Basically, I have one very large matrix `D` and two vectors, `pop` and `trainSetSongs`. The matrix is so large that it becomes pointless to reproduce it here, so instead let's work with random data:

```
D <- matrix(rnorm(44158666), ncol = 7199, nrow = 6134)
pop <- rnorm(6134)
trainSetSongs <- rnorm(7199)
```

I now want to create a `tibble` called `record2`. The code below works, but it can be slow for more indexes.

```
record <- tibble(r = numeric(), row = numeric(), col = numeric())

for (i in 1:100) {
  r <- c()
  DRow <- D[i,] %>%
    order()
  popi <- pop %>%
    nth(i)
  for (j in 1:50) {
    r <- c(r, trainSetSongs[DRow %>%
                             head(j)] %>%
             mean() - popi
    )
  }
  record <- record %>%
    add_row(r = abs(r), row = i, col = 1:50)
  #cat(paste0("\014", i))
}

record2 <- record %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  summarise(r = mean(r))
```

Basically, `record2` has one entry for each column in `D` used (not all of them are because that would be too slow). The second column gives something complicated, perhaps best understood by looking at the code. It's the mean of the absolute value of the difference between the `i`th value in `pop` (`i` marking the row of `D` this process is occuring to) and the mean of `j` values in `trainSetSongs`. Since the index of `trainSetSongs` originally corresponded to the columns of `D`, the values of `trainSetSongs` selected are the ones with the lowest values in the matrix. Therefore, `j` marks the number of columns this process is happening to.

I know this is very confusing (at least, it is to me; I often find myself going over what it all means). My goal is to have a piece of code that doesn't use `for` loops (or doesn't use them as much?), perhaps by reallying on `apply`, `transmute` or other such functions.

**EDIT: NEW VERSION**

After reading the comments, I improved the code the ways I could, but I don't know how to bypass `add_row()`, and I also think there are many ways to improve this code I haven't thought of.

As suggested in the comments, the test data is reduced to:

```
set.seed(123)

D <- matrix(rnorm(50*20), ncol = 50, nrow = 20)
pop <- rnorm(20)
trainSetSongs <- rnorm(50)
```

The `for`s part is now significantly faster already, but still uses `add_row` and two `for` loops. I don't know how to make this more efficient...

```
record <- tibble(r = numeric(), row = numeric(), col = numeric())

for (i in 1:20) {
  r <- rep(0, 50)
  DRow <- order(D[i,])
  popi <- pop[i]
  for (j in 1:50) {
    r[j] <- mean(trainSetSongs[head(DRow,j)]) - popi
  }
  record <- record %>%
    add_row(r = abs(r), row = i, col = 1:50)
}
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same. I decided to also make this nice visualization of the data:

```
record2 <- record %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  summarise(r = mean(r))

ggplot(record2, aes(x = col, y = r))+
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_minimal()+
  xlab("Number of Training Songs")+
  ylab("R")
```

Using this seed and this code, the visualization plot produces something that can be more easily compared later.

[image]

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` (and `tibble`) is a bad thing (`add_row` should be used very sparingly, it is a bad design choice for repeatedly adding things). This anti-practice falls into the second circle of the [*R Inferno*](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (chapter "Growing objects"), since every time you add any rows, it must make complete copies of all rows, and this scales horribly.

Comment: There are other inefficiences here. For instance, `pop %>% nth(i)` is on the order of 20 times *slower* than `pop[i]`, and the latter is far more readable imo; similarly `DRow %>% head(j)` to `head(DRow[j,])`. Your inner `for` loop can likely be reduced (vectorized).

Comment: Frankly, to get more help, I suggest you reduce this problem from a size of `44158666` to something like a size of `40`, use `set.seed` to control the randomness, show the output, and go from there. It's clear that an example of size 40 is good to demonstrate what needs to be done 1M times that size, so efficiency is a good thing. But examples on 44M are much harder to convey than examples on 40.

Comment: Ok, I tried following your suggestions. However, I don't know how to eliminate `add_row()`, nor how to eliminate any `for` loops. This is where I need help the most (and any other ways to make the codemore efficient is also appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a bit to decompose your code, but up front, here's the smaller (and faster) code:

```r
set.seed(123)
D <- matrix(rnorm(50*20), ncol = 50, nrow = 20)
pop <- rnorm(20)
trainSetSongs <- rnorm(50)

cols <- seq_len(ncol(D))
record2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(D)), function(i) {
  r <- cummean(trainSetSongs[order(D[i,])]) - pop[i]
  tibble(r = abs(r), row = i, col = cols)
})
record2 <- bind_rows(record2)
```

After running that, I test accuracy with:

```r
all.equal(record, record2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Breakdown, from the inside out of your code:

- the `for (j..)` inner loop is really just calculating a cumulative mean of `trainSetSongs(order(D[i,]))`, then subtracting the particular `pop` value, so we can use the `cummean` function instead of a `for` loop. The loop itself wasn't bad, but R does things like this as a vector typically much faster than in a loop. For this, we reduce the inner `for` loop to just

  ```r
  r <- cummean(trainSetSongs[order(D[i,])]) - pop[i]
  ```

  (I simplified the assignment to `DRow` and `popi` for simplicity. It's not inefficient to do so, so feel free to make those variables and use them instead, if you prefer the flow.)
- we repeat that for each row of `D`, but instead of a `for` loop appending a row at a time, we keep each new row separate until we have gathered them all into one `list`, then we `dplyr::bind_rows` them all together at once. This can be also be done by filling a `list` in a `for` loop, such as

  ```r
  record2 <- list()
  for (j in seq_len(nrow(D))) {
    # ...
    record2[[j]] <- tibble(...)
  }
  record2 <- bind_rows(record2)
  ```

  (It *used* to be the case that `for` loops were slower in R than `lapply` and family, but it's been several years since that was resolved, so either of those solutions would work.)

If you're curious, the benchmark of this change with this small data is more than double the speed:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                     time          gc               
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                     <list>        <list>           
1 growing      31.7ms   32.4ms      30.8     764KB    185.      2    12     64.9ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1,864 x 3]> <bch:tm [14]> <tibble [14 x 3]>
2 bindrows     14.3ms   14.9ms      66.3     119KB     25.3    21     8    316.8ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [279 x 3]>   <bch:tm [29]> <tibble [29 x 3]>
```

(Two good metrics to pull from that benchmark are `median`, or the median time to execute the relative expression; and `` `itr/sec` ``, the iterations per second. Notice the median time is 32.4ms versus 14.9ms.)

If I run the same process on a `D` of 200x500 instead, the improvement is a bit more dramatic:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                       time         gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                       <list>       <list>          
1 growing       1.64s    1.64s     0.610   630.4MB    14.0      1    23      1.64s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [289,664 x 3]> <bch:tm [1]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 bindrows   155.39ms 163.41ms     6.13      6.1MB     1.53     4     1   652.77ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [2,086 x 3]>   <bch:tm [4]> <tibble [4 x 3]>
```

with a difference of 10x. I'm guessing even larger data will be even faster (relatively) and more efficient.

We could wring even more speed out of it by removing the `tibble` portion and adding `row` and `col` *after* the `lapply` portion. If you need more speed, that's one place to start. Using the larger 200x500 `D` as I suggested, we see

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                       time          gc               
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                       <list>        <list>           
1 growing       1.39s    1.39s     0.721  630.39MB    0.721     1     1      1.39s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [287,277 x 3]> <bch:tm [1]>  <tibble [1 x 3]> 
2 bindrows   164.97ms 260.44ms     3.84     7.24MB    1.92      2     1   520.87ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [2,091 x 3]>   <bch:tm [2]>  <tibble [2 x 3]> 
3 melt         9.89ms  11.06ms    87.1      7.32MB    0        44     0   505.29ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1,062 x 3]>   <bch:tm [44]> <tibble [44 x 3]>
```

for yet another 20x improvement. That code, a little more advanced, is

```r
record3 <- abs(sapply(seq_len(nrow(D)), function(i) {
  cummean(trainSetSongs[order(D[i,])]) - pop[i]
}))
record3 <- setNames(reshape2::melt(record3), c("col", "row", "r"))
record3 <- record3[,c(3,2,1)]
```

Here, we produce a `matrix` instead of a `list`, so after the first `sapply` expression, `record3` is a 500x200 matrix (yes, dims are swapped, that's okay). From here, `reshape2::melt` converts that into a three-column frame, with the values and their column/row numbers.

The last line is mostly cosmetic, but make it to be `all.equal(record,record3)` as before.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! I'm going to dive deep into your code, and it's perfect! Thank you!